# avoiding flicks in header/footer toolbars

Tags: jquery-mobile

The default behavior in jquerymobile when I have header, content and footer (where header/footer are fixed) is that when I scroll the content the header/footer show/hide. I mean when you start scrolling the header/footer hides and when u stop scrolling the header/footer are shown again. On devices its looks very bad/none-user friendly. I want to avoid this show/hide effects of header/footer. Is there any thing thats available in jquerymobile or some of its plugin to avoid it? If nothing then I want to apply iScroll on the content. Can someone guide me how to make data-role="content" using full-screen height?

Answer (score 0):

If [this is what you are referring to](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/css-fixed/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html), then you can just remove the `data-position: fixed`  from the headers and footers. I tried it on the iPhone, and it is still buggy (seems to flicker whenever a touch event it generated, even if it is not necessary).